# Creating illuminate/html selector with Eloquent Models

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to make a selector with Laravel `illuminate/html` and an eloquent models. I need to make it so the option value is `id` and the text displayed is the `name`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FormBuilder `Form::select()` and format your collection to assoc array using `->lists()`:

**PHP:**

```
$models = DB::table('table_name')->lists('name', 'id');
```

**Blade:**

```
{!! Form::select('name', $models) !!}
```

See `lists()`doc [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#selects)